# why two same type components can only set useState in one component type

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been puzzled since half days about my project, which has Setting.js as component and is used in two different locations ( Sidebar.js and Navbar.js ). Navbar will be used for mobile resolution and Sidebar in non-mobile one. If the Setting component exist in both locations , the useState inside Setting.js can be changed only in mobile. For non-mobile resolution, the Setting in Navbar will be displayed none. For more detail, please visit my github https://github.com/BiruSkai/Mini-Reddit/tree/main.  I am a novice and appreciate your support.

Setting.js:

```
import "./setting.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { pageDisplayed } from "../../redux/ducks/SettingSlice";

const Setting = () => {
        const [pages, setPages] = useState(5);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        const handleClickSetting = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                const newPage = document.getElementById("pages").value;
                console.log("newPage in Setting ", newPage)
                setPages(newPage);
                return;
                
        };

        dispatch(pageDisplayed(pages))
        console.log("pages post save ", pages)    
        
        return ( 
                <>
                        <div className="setting">
                                <h6>Setting:</h6>
                                <form>
                                        <label className="setting_subForm">Pages displayed:</label>
                                        <input className="setting_subForm" type="text" id="pages" placeholder={pages}/>
                                        <input className="setting_save" type="submit" value="save" onClick={handleClickSetting}/>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                </>
         );
}
 
export default Setting;
```

Navbar.js:

```
..........
<div className="dropdownIcon" onClick={handleClickDropdown}><IoIosArrowDropdownCircle size={25} /></div>
              <div className="offCanvas">
                <div id="sub-offCanvas">
                  <span className="closeIcon" onClick={closeDropdown}>&#10006;</span>
                  
                  <ul className="navList">
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li ><Setting /></li>
                    <li >About</li>
                    <li >Setting</li>
                    <li >Setting2</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
..........
```

Sidebar.js:

```
import Setting from "../setting/Setting";
import "./sidebar.css";

const Sidebar = () => {
        
        return (
                <>
                        <div className="sidebarContainer"> 
                                <div><Setting /></div>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>About</li>
                                        <li>Setting</li>
                                        <li>Setting2</li>
                                </ul>
                                
                        </div>
                </>
         );
}
 
export default Sidebar;
```

I wish that in non-mobile resolution, pages useState value in Setting.js can be changed by modifying  its value from Setting in Sidebar, while in mobile resoultion, this task will be done by Setting in Navbar.

Regards,

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in Setting.js from sidebar and navbar?

Comment: Hi, I want that react will take the input value #pages of Setting.js in sidebar if >600px resolution (Setting in navbar is displayed none in this case).  In mobile resolution, it has to take the value input Setting in navbar(setting in sidebar is displayed none). The value in input #pages Setting.js will change the pages value of useState( in Setting js). The issue, if Setting component is written in both sidebar and navbar, only the setting in navbar will work.   How should I solve this problem?

Comment: What i understood is that you want to implement responsiveness and for that you can write media query or you can use package like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive.

Comment: Hi, before your latest answer the media query has already been used . If you had time, kindly visit my github as above described ( Repo: mini reddit). The relevant media query are in sidebar and navbar.css. Hence this is  not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have found the solution by myself. I added in navbar.js the folowing code: window.onload = e => {
const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
const settingNavbarId = document.querySelector("#settingNavbar");
if(screenWidth >= 768) {
return settingNavbarId.remove()
}
}